# I am trying to click on submenus of menu on flipkart site

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on Mobile in Electronics category menu on [flipkart](https://www.flipkart.com/)
but I am getting an error:

> "javascript error: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined"

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Here is my code:

```
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Electronics' and @class='_1QZ6fC _3Lgyp8']"));
WebElement sub_menu =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/mobile-phones-store?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mobiles']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(sub_menu).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works. You need to wait until the sub_menu button is visible or clickable.

```java
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Electronics' and @class='_1QZ6fC _3Lgyp8']"));
            WebElement sub_menu =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/mobile-phones-store?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mobiles']"));
            menu.click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(sub_menu));
            sub_menu.click();
```

Comment: thanks for you reply but when i tried given code it gives me following error    element click intercepted: Element <span class="_1QZ6fC _3Lgyp8">...</span> is not clickable at point (125, 76). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_2ISNhP _3AOFWO" tabindex="-1">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)

Comment: So you were not closing the pop up? @minaljadhav

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you need close popup first, then you can achieve `Electronics` menu, and you wrong perform to `Actions`. Try the below code:

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

//close popup
WebElement btnClose = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("._2AkmmA._29YdH8")));
btnClose.click();

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Electronics' and @class='_1QZ6fC _3Lgyp8']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).click(menu).build().perform();

WebElement sub_menu =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/mobile-phones-store?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mobiles']"));
sub_menu.click();
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```